# C3P0 Connection Testing Not Working

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, guice, c3p0

I am building a webapp that uses JPA, Hibernate, and C3P0 to access a MySQL database. So far, it works fine, as long as I don't go over MySQL's wait_timeout. If I try loading a page after that timeout is triggered, I get the following error, and I have to restart my application.

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not prepare statement
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1387) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.7.Final.jar:4.2.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1310) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.7.Final.jar:4.2.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:277) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.7.Final.jar:4.2.7.Final]
at [myApplication].services.ClassroomService.findSessions(ClassroomService.java:155) ~[[myApplication].shared-1.1.6-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.1.6-SNAPSHOT]
at [myApplication].portal.resources.AdminResource.getSessions(AdminResource.java:51) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor30.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_40]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_40]
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60) [jersey-server-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185) [jersey-server-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75) [jersey-server-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302) [jersey-server-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147) [jersey-server-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108) [jersey-server-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147) [jersey-server-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84) [jersey-server-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1511) [jersey-server-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1442) [jersey-server-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1391) [jersey-server-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1381) [jersey-server-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416) [jersey-servlet-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538) [jersey-servlet-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716) [jersey-servlet-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848) [javax.servlet-3.0.0.v201112011016.jar:na]
at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doService(ServletDefinition.java:263) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.service(ServletDefinition.java:178) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedServletPipeline.service(ManagedServletPipeline.java:91) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:62) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
at [myApplication].web.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:59) [[myApplication].shared-1.1.6-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.1.6-SNAPSHOT]
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:163) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:118) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:113) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419) [jetty-servlet-8.1.11.v20130520.jar:8.1.11.v20130520]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:455) [jetty-servlet-8.1.11.v20130520.jar:8.1.11.v20130520]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137) [jetty-server-8.1.11.v20130520.jar:8.1.11.v20130520]
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557) [jetty-security-8.1.11.v20130520.jar:8.1.11.v20130520]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231) [jetty-server-8.1.11.v20130520.jar:8.1.11.v20130520]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1075) [jetty-server-8.1.11.v20130520.jar:8.1.11.v20130520]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:384) [jetty-servlet-8.1.11.v20130520.jar:8.1.11.v20130520]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193) [jetty-server-8.1.11.v20130520.jar:8.1.11.v20130520]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1009) [jetty-server-8.1.11.v20130520.jar:8.1.11.v20130520]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135) [jetty-server-8.1.11.v20130520.jar:8.1.11.v20130520]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255) [jetty-server-8.1.11.v20130520.jar:8.1.11.v20130520]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154) [jetty-server-8.1.11.v20130520.jar:8.1.11.v20130520]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116) [jetty-server-8.1.11.v20130520.jar:8.1.11.v20130520]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370) [jetty-server-8.1.11.v20130520.jar:8.1.11.v20130520]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489) [jetty-server-8.1.11.v20130520.jar:8.1.11.v20130520]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:949) [jetty-server-8.1.11.v20130520.jar:8.1.11.v20130520]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1011) [jetty-server-8.1.11.v20130520.jar:8.1.11.v20130520]
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644) [jetty-http-8.1.11.v20130520.jar:8.1.11.v20130520]
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235) [jetty-http-8.1.11.v20130520.jar:8.1.11.v20130520]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82) [jetty-server-8.1.11.v20130520.jar:8.1.11.v20130520]
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:668) [jetty-io-8.1.11.v20130520.jar:8.1.11.v20130520]
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52) [jetty-io-8.1.11.v20130520.jar:8.1.11.v20130520]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608) [jetty-util-8.1.11.v20130520.jar:8.1.11.v20130520]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543) [jetty-util-8.1.11.v20130520.jar:8.1.11.v20130520]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [na:1.7.0_40]
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not prepare statement
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.Final.jar:4.2.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.Final.jar:4.2.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.Final.jar:4.2.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:188) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.Final.jar:4.2.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:159) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.Final.jar:4.2.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1859) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.Final.jar:4.2.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1836) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.Final.jar:4.2.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1816) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.Final.jar:4.2.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:900) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.Final.jar:4.2.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:342) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.Final.jar:4.2.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2526) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.Final.jar:4.2.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2512) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.Final.jar:4.2.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2342) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.Final.jar:4.2.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2337) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.Final.jar:4.2.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:495) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.Final.jar:4.2.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:357) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.Final.jar:4.2.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:195) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.Final.jar:4.2.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1275) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.Final.jar:4.2.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.Final.jar:4.2.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:268) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.7.Final.jar:4.2.7.Final]
... 55 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.Connection was implicitly closed due to underlying exception/error:


** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException
MESSAGE: Communications link failure

Last packet sent to the server was 0 ms ago.

STACKTRACE:

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

Last packet sent to the server was 0 ms ago.
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1074)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2985)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2871)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3414)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1936)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2060)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2542)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1734)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1885)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:116)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:56)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2040)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1837)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1816)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:900)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:342)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2526)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2512)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2342)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2337)
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:495)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:357)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:195)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1275)
at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101)
at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:268)
at [myApplication].services.ClassroomService.findSessions(ClassroomService.java:155)
at [myApplication].portal.resources.AdminResource.getSessions(AdminResource.java:51)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1511)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1442)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1391)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1381)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doService(ServletDefinition.java:263)
at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.service(ServletDefinition.java:178)
at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedServletPipeline.service(ManagedServletPipeline.java:91)
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:62)
at [myApplication].web.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:59)
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:163)
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58)
at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:118)
at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:113)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:455)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1075)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:384)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1009)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:949)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1011)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:668)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:2431)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2882)
... 80 more


** END NESTED EXCEPTION **


at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_40]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_40]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.7.0_40]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526) ~[na:1.7.0_40]
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:na]
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:na]
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:984) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:na]
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:na]
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:926) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:na]
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.checkClosed(ConnectionImpl.java:1098) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:na]
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:4076) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:na]
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:4042) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:na]
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection.prepareStatement(NewProxyConnection.java:162) ~[c3p0-0.9.2.1.jar:0.9.2.1]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:161) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.Final.jar:4.2.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:182) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.Final.jar:4.2.7.Final]
... 71 common frames omitted
Nov 26, 2013 11:40:43 AM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse logException
SEVERE: Mapped exception to response: 500 (Internal Server Error)
[myApplication].api.ResourceException
at [myApplication].portal.resources.AdminResource.getSessions(AdminResource.java:68)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor30.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1511)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1442)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1391)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1381)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doService(ServletDefinition.java:263)
at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.service(ServletDefinition.java:178)
at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedServletPipeline.service(ManagedServletPipeline.java:91)
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:62)
at [myApplication].web.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:59)
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:163)
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58)
at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:118)
at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:113)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:455)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1075)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:384)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1009)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:949)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1011)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:668)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

I also sometimes get a `JDBCConnectionException: could not extract ResultSet`, but that stems from the same `Communications Link Failure`.

Usually, C3P0 can be configured to test whether a connection is valid before using, and I tried implementing it, but it doesn't seem to work. I'm also using Guice, and I'm thinking something is going screwy when I use `@Inject` to get an EntityManager.

Does anyone know what's going on here? I've looked through pretty much anything that might help, but I haven't found anything yet. I'm about to try switching to Apache DBCP to see if that works any better.

Thanks,
Tyler

PS: Here's my persistence.xml and c3p0-config.xml, in case that'll help.

**persistence.xml**

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="wam" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>myApplication.beans.AnswerBean</class>
        <class>myApplication.beans.ConfigBean</class>
        <class>myApplication.beans.CourseBean</class>
        <class>myApplication.beans.DealerBean</class>
        <class>myApplication.beans.LocationBean</class>
        <class>myApplication.beans.TrainerBean</class>
        <class>myApplication.beans.PositionBean</class>
        <class>myApplication.beans.QuestionBean</class>
        <class>myApplication.beans.SessionBean</class>
        <class>myApplication.beans.StudentBean</class>
        <!-- See '/etc/setup.txt' for how to setup using MS-SQL * Change driver/dialect
            (H2=H2Dialect / MSSQL=SQLServerDialect) * Change url below (jdbc.url)
            * Change
            user/password (jdbc.user and password) OPTIONAL: * Create Database first
            (ie maildb) * Change hbm2ddl -->
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="${portal.db.driver}" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="${portal.db.url}" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="${portal.db.user}" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="${portal.db.pass}" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="${portal.db.dialect}" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.shutdown" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="${stats}"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="${portal.db.schema}" />
            <!-- Caching -->
            <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory"/>
            <property name="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName" value="ehcache.xml" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true" />
            <!-- Pooling -->
            <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**c3p0-config.xml**

```
<c3p0-config>
    <default-config>
        <property name="acquireIncrement">3</property>
        <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod">9</property>
        <property name="maxConnectionAge">30</property>
        <property name="maxIdleTime">10</property>
        <property name="maxPoolSize">25</property>
        <property name="maxStatements">0</property>
        <property name="minPoolSize">5</property>
        <property name="preferredTestQuery">SELECT 1</property>
        <property name="testConnectionOnCheckin">true</property>
    </default-config>
</c3p0-config>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, my problem wasn't with how C3P0 was working, but how Guice was making EntityManagers. I ended up adding `filter("/*").through(PersistFilter.class);` where I was making my persist modules, and that fixed the problem. Granted, it revealed a couple problems with eager singletons, but I'll leave that for another thread.

Answer (score 0):

1) verify that the configuration you intend is actually the configuration that is taking hold. c3p0 pools dump their configuration to log at INFO on initialization. alternatively, you can check via JMX. if Guice is programmatically overriding the defaults you set in config, you should see that in the dumped config.

2) how are you managing your hibernate Sessions? are you close()ing them promptly, or reusing long-lived Sessions. if the latter, don't. when using a Connection pool, a Session should perform a unit-of-work defined as the full set of operations a client is able to perform without waiting for further interaction. once that work is completed, the Session should be promptly close()ed. keeping long-lived open Sessions is a terrible but unfortunately common practice; it defeats both the purpose of a Connection pool and its ability to ensure, e.g. in this case, liveness.

p.s. you're setting both `testConnectionOnCheckout` and `testConnectionOnCheckin`. that's probably overkill `testConnectionOnCheckout` is sufficient, simple and reliable but exacts a performance tax within clients' codepath. to avoid that tax (at cost of a bit of reliablility, combine `testConnectionOnCheckin` with `idleConnectionTestPeriod`. See http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_connection_testing

Comment: 1) It looks like my configuration is taking hold. I actually had a similar error before this one involving that.

Comment: 2) To be honest, I don't completely know. It looks like sessions can stay open for a while, but I was told that hibernate managed connections on its own. If it doesn't, would there be a workaround? This project is almost done, so a structure change (which I think this would turn out to be) is less than feasible.

p.s. -- That must've been from when I was playing with settings. I removed `testConnectionOnCheckout`.

Comment: Another thought: would changing the pooling to Apache DBCP change the behavior at all?

Comment: Yet another bit of information: sessions are in fact closed as soon as we're done with them, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: if you removed testConnectionOnCheckout, be sure to add idleConnectionTestPeriod. i'd start with only testConnectionOnCheckout, then move to testConnectionOnCheckin/idleConnectionTestPeriod, again see the advice in the green box here http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_connection_testing

Comment: hibernate manages Connections for you, underneath Sessions. you have to manage Sessions. your app should be opening them as needed, and close()ing them when a client is done. if you are holding Sessions open for long periods, eventually the Connections underneath will timeout. i don't think moving to another Connection pool will change that, though you can try. within c3p0, you can try the setting unreturnedConnectionTimeout to see whether prolonged Sessions are the problem. if you set it to 120 (ie 2 minutes), most reasonable applications should be fine w/that. do you start seeing Exceptions?

Comment: you may be surprised how easy it is to fix, though, if naive caching of Sessions is the problem. just see how your clients are getting hold of hibernate Sessions. if there are Sessions held in variables or Collections, get rid of that. Only the SessionFactory should be held that way. fetch Sessions on an as-needed basis from the SessionFactory.

Comment: if you can't figure anything out, and you are not holding Sessions open, an easy fix is to set a maxConnectionAge less than the timeout you see. it'd be better to understand how timed-out Connections are getting past your tests, but as long as maxConnectionAge is large (say more than 1800 seconds, but you should go as large as you can while still avoiding timeouts), the performance cost will be negligible.